# How to import a SharePoint 2010 list at a specific version using powershell?

Tags: 2010, list, powershell, import, version

I exported a list with the "all versions" option. I would like to import it at a previous version. How can I know the available versions and how to select the one that I want and import it?

Answer (score 1):

The All Versions command, doesn't mean versions of the list, but means it exports all versions of all list items. When the list is then imported, the entire version history of the list items is present instead of the most recent version.

Comment: Thank you. That wasn't the answer I was expected but actually, it does help me out.